# Conditionally creating rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

`A

0   a-7,5,1,6,63,101,39,1
1   c-2,7,10,12,27,40,71,78`

I have a dataframe quite similar to the one above.
The letters preceding the `-` in each row represents an id
Each of the comma separated values represent an entry in the dataframe.

How do i conditionally format this row such that I end up getting something like:

`id A 
0 a  7 
0 a  5
0 a  1
0 a  6
0 a  63
0 a  10
1 c  2 
1 c  10
1 c  12
1 c  27
1 c  40`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `-` for 2 columns DataFrame, then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `Series`, split by `,` and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html). Last some data cleaning by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = (df['A'].str.split('-', expand=True)
             .set_index(0)[1]
             .str.split(',', expand=True)
             .unstack()
             .sort_index(level=1)
             .reset_index(level=0, name='a')
             .reset_index(drop=True))
df.columns = ['id','A']
```

Alternatively you can use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) for flattening:

```
df = df['A'].str.split('-', expand=True) 
a = df[1].str.split(',')
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.repeat(df[0].values, a.str.len()),
                   'A' : np.concatenate(a)}, columns=['id','A'])
print (df)
   id    A
0   a    7
1   a    5
2   a    1
3   a    6
4   a   63
5   a  101
6   a   39
7   a    1
8   c    2
9   c    7
10  c   10
11  c   12
12  c   27
13  c   40
14  c   71
15  c   78
```

Comment: You should get 200k today/tonight (-:  Congrats!

Comment: @piRSquared - Yes, it seems so, thanks. for you plus1 too ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
With a `np.repeat` and `pd.Series.str.count`
The way this works is that I'm going to repeat the values at the beginning of the string an amount of times that is equal to the number of commas I find plus one.  For the second column, I join the strings together with commas, then separate the whole thing by commas.

```
s = df.A.str.split('-', 1)
pd.DataFrame(dict(
    id=np.repeat(
        s.str[0].values,
        s.str[1].str.count(',') + 1
    ),
    A=s.str[1].str.cat(sep=',').split(',')
))

      A id
0     7  a
1     5  a
2     1  a
3     6  a
4    63  a
5   101  a
6    39  a
7     1  a
8     2  c
9     7  c
10   10  c
11   12  c
12   27  c
13   40  c
14   71  c
15   78  c
```

---

**Option 2**
Using comprehensions
This seems more intuitive to me.  It's essentially a product or double for loop wrapped in a comprehension.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [(i, a) for i, b in (
        x.split('-', 1) for x in df.A
    ) for a in b.split(',')],
    columns=['id', 'A']
)

   id    A
0   a    7
1   a    5
2   a    1
3   a    6
4   a   63
5   a  101
6   a   39
7   a    1
8   c    2
9   c    7
10  c   10
11  c   12
12  c   27
13  c   40
14  c   71
15  c   78
```